Tie to VDDIO for I²C Interface
I want to communicate to a sensor that supports I2C and SPI. I want to use I2C and the datasheet says "Tie CS to VDDIO for I²C Interface", do I need to connect a resistor to limit the current?

No, CS (chip select) is an input and will not draw any significant amount of current. No series resistor is needed.
In general, when a datasheet says to "tie" pins, it means a direct connection with nothing in-between. You should always follow the datasheet instructions unless you have a very good reason not to as the chip might malfunction otherwise.
